# PHP: Edit entry in array depending on value from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how I can change a value in a array if the corresponding value in another array is 0.
For all Speed[x] = 0 the corresponding Direction[x] is also = 0.

Given the two arrays below:

```
Speed
(
    [0] => 2.2
    [1] => 1.3
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1.1
)

Direction
(
    [0] => 126.2
    [1] => 159.8
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 163.8
)
```

I need to loop through the Direction array and change all values that has a corresponding 0 entry in the Speed array to the previous entry in the Direction array that is bigger than 0 .

So if Speed [2], Speed [3], Speed [4] = 0 then Direction[2], Direction [3], Direction [4] should be = Direction [1] in the example below since Direction[1] is the first previous entry bigger than 0.

That would give me:

```
Speed
(
    [0] => 2.2
    [1] => 1.3
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1.1
)

Direction
(
    [0] => 126.2
    [1] => 159.8
    [2] => 159.8
    [3] => 159.8
    [4] => 159.8
    [5] => 163.8
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I could get this done?

Comment: `for`/`foreach` loop. Are you familiar with them? Or just expect someone to write code for you?

Comment: checkout how `foreach ($input as $key => $value)` works can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Replacing Direction Array Value with after/before element when you find speed array value to 0**

```
<?php
    $Speed = array("2.2","1.3","0","1.8","1.2");
    $Direction = array("159.2","159.8","0","161.4","1.2");
    for($i=0;$i<count($Speed);$i++)
    {
        if($Speed[$i] == '0')
        {
            $Direction[$i] = $Direction[1];
        }
    }
    print_r($arr2);
    ?>
```

o/p
Array ( [0] => 159.2 [1] => 159.8 [2] => 159.8 [3] => 161.4 [4] => 1.2 )

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. What if I need to select not the previous value, but the last value that is > 0?

Comment: last mean Direction arrays last value??

Comment: Yes, thats' correct last direction value bigger than 0.

Comment: if(end($arr2) != '0') { $arr2[$i] = end($arr2);  } //Checking last element of array is not zero than assign value to it

Comment: no he might be asking for this  :  if($arr2[$i-1] == 0){$arr2[$i] = $arr2[$i-2]}

Comment: i should have stated previous value not last value. I'm looking for the last entry before $i that has a value bigger than 0 and not the last entry of the array.

Comment: so if speed[2] = 0 then the direction[2] is replaced by >0 value from same array elements??

Comment: If speed[2] = 0 and direction[1] = 0 then I want direction[2] to be = direction[0] if direction[0] is bigger than 0.

Comment: please edit question in a manner which output should came out then i will edit my answer and give a proper answer

Comment: That would only select Direction [1] every time. I need it to be dynamic and find the previous entry that has a  value higher than 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($speed);$i++){
 if($speed[$i] == 0){
   $direction[$i] = $direction[$i-1];
   }
 }
```